# How to reset noUiSlider value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reset, nouislider

I have a slider:

```
jQuery('#rating_price').noUiSlider({
    start: [50,500],
    range: {
        'min': 50,
        '1%': [ 1,1 ],
        'max': 500
    }
});
```

I want to reset it, but it WILL NOT reset!

```
jQuery('#rating_price').noUiSlider("move", {
    setTo: [50, 500]
});
```

I've checked other questions and tried many different variations. What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to use the following but it gives me an error:

```
jQuery('#rating_price').noUiSlider.set([50,500]);
```

> .set is not a function.

The following doesnt work

```
jQuery('#rating_price').noUiSlider.set([50, 500]);
```

It shouldn't be this hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

https://github.com/leongersen/noUiSlider/issues/304

jQuery('#rating_price').val([50, 500]);

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you still reach this page,[the documented way of resetting the noUiSlider](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-read-write/) is to call reset() method on the instance to reinstate the original start values.

```
slider.noUiSlider.reset(); //where the slider is var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
```

Note the new version doesnt use jQuery element, so if you use, jQuery, you may need this:

```
jQuery('#rating_price')[0].noUiSlider.reset();
```